# Ubuntu 18 external monitor resoolution

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, external-monitor

I have installed ubuntu 18 on my MacBook Pro retina 15', and it works fine.

However, when I plug my external Samsung monitor, the built-in screen resolution is kept the same but the external monitor seems to be zoomed by 200%.

Checking the settings I can indeed see that both the built-in and external monitor have 200% resolution.

How can I set the external monitor resolution to 100% while keeping the built-in one to 200%?

[Screen of both displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7gpA.png)

On the left the external monitor, on the right the built-in one. It's not very clear, but trust me the external monitor is way too zoomed.

Also, some of my desktop icons appear on the monitor and some others on my built-in laptop.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What happens if you change the external monitor's scale to 100%?

Comment: also the built-in screen scales to 100%, which is too small

Comment: Have you tried [this workaround](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Multiple_displays)?

Comment: It works only if the external screen is set to the right of the built-in one. Putting it on the left with `left-of` will make part of the built in screen appear on the monitor.  Also, I noticed that moving the mouse from the external to the built monitor makes it blink very fast. It does not seem to be a clean or permanent solution, but it works

Comment: Edit: after just 2-3 minutes of usage, the blinking cursor is very annoying. And this only happens when the external monitor is plugged

Comment: Edit 2: after running `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` I now only move the cursor in the upper left quarter of the external monitor. The cursor is still annoyingly blinking.